# How to read child nodes of an xml file from the current node

Tags: xml, vb.net

This is my first post.  Hence pardon me if I have done anything improperly.

I would like to read all the child nodes **from** the current node.  To explain further, I have created a nodelist and for each node I want to determine the following :
01. Find how many child nodes are there for the current node.
02. Generate a list of such node names.
03. For one node I have multiple child nodes  of same name.  How to get their values without always getting the value of the first node.
04. I have attached my code as well as xml fragment.
05. What I want is to extract the -183336 in Line 52 and 183336 in Line 76 of the xml doc.
06. Solutions required in VB.Net

Environment
Windows 8, VS 2013 Express.Windows Form Application
Would appreciate help.
Best Regards
Varadarajan R

Code

```
Private Sub VCHLED_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VCHLED.Click

    Me.Text = gApplicationTitle + gUsedDataBase

    '' cleanup the xml file to remove unwanted / complicating text

    gXMLFile = "VOUCHER1.XML"
    gXMLFilewithFullPath = gXMLFileLocation + gXMLFile

    gXMLTag = "VOUCHER"

    '' Handle xml file

    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load(gXMLFilewithFullPath)
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("VOUCHER")
    Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(gXMLFilewithFullPath)
    Dim root As XmlElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
    Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName(gXMLTag)

    ' Determine how many nodes are there

    Dim NoOfNodes As Integer = elemList.Count()
    Dim NumberOfLoops As Integer = 1
    NumberOfLoops = Int(NoOfNodes / gMaxRowsForInsert) + 1


    '' Declare the Variables


    Dim mVchGuid As String
    Dim mLedgerName As String
    Dim mIsDeemedPositIve As String
    Dim mAmount As String

    Dim mMasterID As Integer
    Dim mAmountDr As Decimal
    Dim mAmountCr As Decimal


    Dim LoopsFinished As Integer = 0

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes

        Dim NodeName As String = node.Name
        Debug.WriteLine(NodeName)
        If node.HasChildNodes Then
            Dim Children As Integer = node.ChildNodes.Count()
            Debug.WriteLine(" Child Nodes " + Children.ToString)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For i = 0 To Children - 1
                If node.SelectSingleNode("VOUCHER/ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST/AMOUNT") Is Nothing Then
                    mAmount = ""
                Else
                    mAmount = node.SelectSingleNode("VOUCHER/ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST/AMOUNT").InnerText
                    Debug.WriteLine(" Amount : " + mAmount)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Next
        End Sub
```

XML Fragment

```
<VOUCHER REMOTEID="1893406f-af1d-4d97-9b33-340f44694509-00002102" VCHKEY="1893406f-af1d-4d97-9b33-340f44694509-0000a303:00000010" VCHTYPE="Journal Voucher" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
   <DATE>20140403</DATE>
   <GUID>1893406f-af1d-4d97-9b33-340f44694509-00002102</GUID>
   <NARRATION>Sra no.65 and 82 / 28.03.2014</NARRATION>
   <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Journal Voucher</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
   <VOUCHERNUMBER>JV/NF/00003/KM/14-15</VOUCHERNUMBER>
   <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Sri Lakshmi Fibre Coirs</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
   <PERSISTEDVIEW>Accounting Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
   <VCHGSTCLASS/>
   <ENTEREDBY>kkdsph</ENTEREDBY>
   <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
   <AUDITED>No</AUDITED>
   <FORJOBCOSTING>No</FORJOBCOSTING>
   <ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL>
   <EFFECTIVEDATE>20140403</EFFECTIVEDATE>
   <ISFORJOBWORKIN>No</ISFORJOBWORKIN>
   <ALLOWCONSUMPTION>No</ALLOWCONSUMPTION>
   <USEFORINTEREST>No</USEFORINTEREST>
   <USEFORGAINLOSS>No</USEFORGAINLOSS>
   <USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>No</USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>
   <USEFORCOMPOUND>No</USEFORCOMPOUND>
   <ALTERID> 9852</ALTERID>
   <EXCISEOPENING>No</EXCISEOPENING>
   <USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>No</USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>
   <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
   <HASCASHFLOW>No</HASCASHFLOW>
   <ISPOSTDATED>No</ISPOSTDATED>
   <USETRACKINGNUMBER>No</USETRACKINGNUMBER>
   <ISINVOICE>No</ISINVOICE>
   <MFGJOURNAL>No</MFGJOURNAL>
   <HASDISCOUNTS>No</HASDISCOUNTS>
   <ASPAYSLIP>No</ASPAYSLIP>
   <ISCOSTCENTRE>No</ISCOSTCENTRE>
   <ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>No</ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>
   <ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>No</ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>
   <ISBLANKCHEQUE>No</ISBLANKCHEQUE>
   <ISVOID>No</ISVOID>
   <ISONHOLD>No</ISONHOLD>
   <ISDELETED>No</ISDELETED>
   <ASORIGINAL>No</ASORIGINAL>
   <VCHISFROMSYNC>No</VCHISFROMSYNC>
   <MASTERID> 8450</MASTERID>
   <VOUCHERKEY>179233280229392</VOUCHERKEY>
   <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
    <LEDGERNAME>Sri Lakshmi Fibre Coirs</LEDGERNAME>
    <GSTCLASS/>
    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
    <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
    <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
    <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <AMOUNT>-183336.00</AMOUNT>
    <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
     <NAME>163</NAME>
     <BILLCREDITPERIOD>24-Mar-2014</BILLCREDITPERIOD>
     <BILLTYPE>Agst Ref</BILLTYPE>
     <TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>No</TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>
     <AMOUNT>-73353.00</AMOUNT>
     <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>     </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
    </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
    <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
     <NAME>164</NAME>
     <BILLCREDITPERIOD>28-Mar-2014</BILLCREDITPERIOD>
     <BILLTYPE>Agst Ref</BILLTYPE>
     <TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>No</TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>
     <AMOUNT>-109983.00</AMOUNT>
   </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
   <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
    <LEDGERNAME>Company</LEDGERNAME>
    <GSTCLASS/>
    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
    <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
    <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
    <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <AMOUNT>183336.00</AMOUNT>
   </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     </VOUCHER>
```

Comment: You seem to be asking for a lot of answers, instead of just one problem that you have attempted to fix and are having trouble on. Unfortunately, there are not code elves in here to code for you but instead help you with an issue. I suggest looking at some XML reading examples and tutorials such as these: http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/xml.asp  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET

Comment: Thank you sparkysword.  Will go through your recommendations.

Comment: @sparkysword - I tried from what you recommended.  Still unable to get the result I want.  Would appreciate further help.

Comment: What did you try? For what problem? How did it not work? You are not giving me specifics, and although you might not realize it, you sound like you're asking people to do the work for you. Answer these questions first and edit your original post.